# Turn off app in IOS through PhoneGap API

Tags: iphone, ios, html, cordova

I have a html5 app for iphone using phonegap. I check for internet connection for the necessary first update, how do I turn of the app if the user does not have an internet connection? Thanks in advance. As I said I have full access to phonegap api!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to deploy your app to the app store, you can not update the app under the covers. You have to submita new version to apple and let the users update your app.

If you just want to know wether your device is online you can use the Phonegap online offline events. See: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_events_events.md.html#online and http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_events_events.md.html#offline

Comment: I guess I was a bit unclear, when the app starts it got certain stuff that is read from a webpage. Initially those fields are empty and it needs to read them the first time it starts (or any other time unless the first "update" was successfull). So, if the internetconnection or the user decides to cancel the first "update" from the internet or it doesn't succeed, whatever, the app needs to be shut down. How do I do that from JS, HTML5 or Phonegap or JQuery Mobile? Thanks in advance

Comment: well as I said in my answer, detect if the device is online, if its offline update your view to tell the user to go online, as soon as its online load your data